# JavaScript displays infinity. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to just display the minimum number but instead it displays the min number and infinity Why am I getting infinity? How do I get rid of it?

```
var repeat, studentArr = [], markArr = [];
while (repeat !== 'n' && repeat !== 'N'){
    studentArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
    markArr.push(parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: ")));
    repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}  
var largest = max(markArr);

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, markArr);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(Math, markArr);
};
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, markArr),
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, markArr);


document.write(min);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `Math.min.apply(Math, markArr)` - comparing markArr with Math?

Comment: @cale_b: That takes the minimum element of `markArr`.

Comment: You sould use *confirm* instead of prompt so you get a Boolean response.

Comment: i want to get the minimum value the user inputs to the array witch it does but it also displays infinity why? and how do i fix this?

Comment: `var largest = max(markArr);` This is not how you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, markArr);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(Math, markArr);
};
```

These aren’t good prototype definitions; they’re tied to one object! Make them use `this` instead.

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, this);
};
```

Apart from that, `max` isn’t a function at the time you call it to obtain `latest` (it should be `undefined`), and you’re not using these functions, either. I’m surprised you can get Infinity at all.

```
var min = markArr.min();
var max = markArr.max();

document.write(min);
```

Or we can just stop using prototypes; [this fiddle works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/UBBUQ/).

Comment: it still displays infinity tho how do i get rid of it?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Did you use the jsFiddle? The only way you’d be getting `Infinity` would be by having an empty array. I’m not even sure if that’s possible with what you have… the alternative would be you entering a really huge mark. As in 900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Comment: no thats all i have in the code above i cant understand why i keeps printing infinity

Comment: @HelloWorld: No, it’s really not. You would have received an error at `var largest = max(markArr);`.

Comment: var repeate = true;


var repeat, studentArr = [], markArr = [];
while (repeat !== 'n' && repeat !== 'N'){
    studentArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
    markArr.push(parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: ")));
    repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}  

Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, this);
};
var min = markArr.min();
var max = markArr.max();

 
 document.write(min);

Comment: @HelloWorld: And what kind of input did you give it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the array itself. If the method is called on the array, then *this* within the method will be the array, so:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};
```

Do the same to other methods.

Note that extending *Array.prototype* will affect *for..in* enumeration over arrays so that a *hasOwnProperty* test will be required to filter out enumerable properties on the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

`Infinity` issue can be raised also when you use `Math.max` with non-integer .

Then ,it is better to call `map`  before calling `max` :

## i.e :

```
urArray.map(function(e){return parseInt(e);/*or parseFloat()*/}).max()
```